# Whether iterating collection using a iterator is more effecient than normal iteration

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a collection like follows:

```
  final List list = new ArrayList(3);
```

Is it effecient to do something like below

```
    for (final Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

OR

```
for(final Object obj : list){
// do something 
}
```

?

Comment: Usually code clarity is more important than worrying about performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example is just a shortcut syntax for the first one. They're essentially the same thing (assuming you call `final Object obj = iter.next();` in your `for` loop).

The shortcut syntax, known as "for-each" or "enhanced for", is more typically used since it's cleaner, more intuitive, and as [Péter Török notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636424/whether-iterating-collection-using-a-iterator-is-more-effecient-than-normal-iter/9636451#comment12232257_9636451) avoids potential bugs. I only recommend the plain syntax when it's needed for its greater flexibility.

See this article for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: Moreover, the second example is safer, as it avoids some potential bugs which may occur using the first form (especially in nested loops).